# Apostrophe from a database field in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, mysqli

I made a rookie mistake when handling form data with my PHP and Javascript app where I did not anticipate and support apostrophes (') in a text field.

Even more troubling, in a multi ten thousand line app I used single quotes, or ' ' to enclose variables that included HTML and variables that could include the apostrophe from this same table, instead of using quotes (" ") and escaping the html.

Before I modify the $_POST data that is entered into the MySQL data using the PHP function [real_escape_string function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php), which still stores the text with the apostrophe, without slashes. Then following that up with modifying every instance where a variable is defined with an apostrophe and changing it to quotations (" ") and then escaping, I wanted to ask here if I was missing something.

Here is an example of what I can do to the $_POST data using the PHP/Mysql function above

> $db->real_escape_string($_POST["name"])
>   where "name" = O'Brien
>   In the Database is stored as O'Brien, not O\'Brien

When I read this data into the front-end it is being done like this:

```js
var options = '<option value="<?php echo $row[$name];?>" selected><?php echo $row[$name];?></option>';
```

In these cases when the name includes an apostrophe, javascript console throws an error "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list", which makes sense.

I am hoping for suggestions for how to solve this with the lowest effort/time, but done the RIGHT way, that doesn't cause any issues when using apostrophe's or even quotes in the future.

Comment: so why don't you just wrap your js in double quotes instead and then escape the double quotes inside that? seems like it will work.

Comment: It would be too much work, but also trying to understand the right thing to do here.

Comment: `var options = "<option value=\"<?php echo $row[$name];?>\" selected><?php echo $row[$name];?></option>";` - That wasn't too much work, unless you have way too many of these that you're not showing.

Comment: Yes...many thousands of these with different variables and statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use prepared statements and parameterize the query instead of escaping (and swapping quote types, I'm not clear why you are doing that).

However these methods are unrelated to your current issue. Currently you are experience the affects of incorrect encapsulation when outputting, and also would be open to an XSS injection. You should use http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php for outputting to the browser.

```
 var options = '<option value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($row[$name], ENT_QUOTES);?>" selected><?php echo htmlspecialchars($row[$name] , ENT_QUOTES);?></option>';
```

But you also should read, https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#Why_Can.27t_I_Just_HTML_Entity_Encode_Untrusted_Data.3F, because you are in JS, not HTML, so this probably won't be sufficient.

Comment: I am going to take your advice and learn more about prepared statements and parameterizing the query.

For the case of this, all the MYSQL queries are being run in a different file, so would you suggest I try to use htmlspecialchars, at the source?

Also with regards to XSS injections, I'm at risk of that now since there are certain form fields, which when submitted via $_POST are called in javascript code which have incorrect encapsulation. How would you suggest correcting that?

If I encapsulated variables with double quotes (") won't I have the same issue if the text contains "?

Comment: If you convert to the entities you will not have quotes you will have `&#39` or `&#34;` (I think, might be `&quot;` either way it wont break). `htmlspecialchars` should be used for outputting, I'm not clear what you mean by at the source but if you mean when storing then no.

Comment: Gotcha, so use mysql's function to store the apostrophe item, and for outputting specifically htmlspecialchars every and all text fields, right?

Comment: Basically, if you are outputting to JS though be careful something like `alert(js_var);` would still fire because none of those are special characters. If encapsulated in quotes though it'd be safe because it'd just be a string

Comment: Just wanted to say, I ended up taking the effort to re-write using prepared statements and feel a lot better.